# std::vector for parent and child class

Tags: c++, stdvector

I need to create a vector that can contain my parent class and sub class data.

This is what i do..

**Vehicle is the parent class**

**Car is the child class**

About Car.cpp , it got the following

```
struct Point
{
    int x,y
};

class Car : public Vehicle
{
private:
    Point wheelPoint[4];
    double area;

public:
    void setPoint();
};

void Car::setPoint()
{
    int xData,yData;

    cout << "Please enter X:";
    cin >> xData;

    cout << "Please enter Y:";
    cin >> yData;

    wheelPoint[i].x = xData;
    wheelPoint[i].y = yData;
}
```

Then at my main.cpp

At my main.cpp

```
vector<VehicleTwoD> list;
VehicleTwoD *vehicle;
Car *car = new Car;
string vehicleName;

cout << "Please input name of vehicle";
cin >> vehicleName;

vehicle = new Car;
car->setPoint();

list.push_back( Vehicle() );
list.back().setName(vehicleName);
```

Here the issues.. how i put my wheelPoint of car into this vector also.

What i want to achieve is a vector that can contain

```
Vehicle Name: Vehicle Name (private variable at Vehicle - Parent Class)
Wheel Point[0]: Point (X,Y) ( private var at Car - Child Class)
Wheel Point[1]: Point (X,Y) ( private var at Car - Child Class)
Wheel Point[2]: Point (X,Y) ( private var at Car - Child Class)
Wheel Point[3]: Point (X,Y) ( private var at Car - Child Class)
```

Comment: What is `Vechicle2D`? The way to create vector that can contain both your parent class and your child class is to have a vector of *pointers* to your parent class, and to use *virtual functions*, `vector<Vehicle*>` in other words.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Containers of objects suffer from object slicing. You'll need a vector of pointers (preferably smart):

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<Vechicle>> vehicleVector;
```

to which you can do:

```
vehicleVector.push_back(new Vehicle);
vehicleVector.push_back(new Car);
```

Having a vector of objects will cut off all type information that is beyond `Vechicle` - so, a `Car` will be turned into a `Vehicle`, losing all additional information.

Comment: The OP seems to be confused about how polymorphism works, based on how he does `list.push_back( Vehicle() );` and `list.back().setName(vehicleName);` instead of `car->setName(vehicleName);` and `list.push_back(car);`.

Comment: doesnt really work for me.. i try to push_back new Car but it dont seems to work

Comment: @user1777711 Well that's because you are doing it wrong. But without *real code* it's hard to know why.

Comment: @user1777711 did you change the declaration of the vector?

Comment: @user1777711 did you `#include <memory>`?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and I fixed it by first using  and then compiling using c++14. 11 will work as well but I wanted to use some of 14's new features so I did that. I hope this helps!

```
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Shape>> _shapes;
```