# C++ Adding objects of child classes to a vector of a parent class

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, vector, object-slicing

I have the following class hierarchy:
[Crocodile Class extends from Oviparous which extends from Animal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwOp4.png)

I need to store objects of type Crocodile, Goose, Pelican, Bat, Whale and SeaLion inside a vector, so:

1- I create the global vector:

```
vector<Animal*> animals;
```

2- I add objects (Crocodile, Goose, Pelican, Bat, Whale, SeaLion) to the vector:

```
animals.push_back(new Crocodile(name, code, numberofEggs));
```

3- I loop through the vector to print each object on a table

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < animals.size(); ++i){
    /* now the problem is here, each animal[i] is of type = "Animal", not Crocodile, or Goose, etc..
   /* so when I try to do something like the line below it doesn't work because it can't find the method because that method is not on the Animal Class of course */
   cout << animals[i]->GetName(); // THIS WORK
   cout << animals[i]->GetNumberofEggs(); //THIS DOESN'T WORK
   /* when I debug using the line below, every object on the vector is returning "P6Animal" */
   cout << typeid(animals[i]).name(); // P6Animal instead of Crocodile
}
```

I think it is related with this post [std::vector for parent and child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091302/stdvector-for-parent-and-child-class) and I think the problem is object slicing, so I tried creating the vector like this:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Animal>> animals;
//and adding the objects like this
animals.push_back(unique_ptr<Animal>(new Crocodile(name, code, numberofEggs)));
```

But nothing

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Since you're using pointers it is not a slicing problem. Using a smart pointer is better than a raw pointer though, so keep using that. I suspect what is happening is that you do not have the `GetNumberofEggs()` function in your base class. Please work on a [mcve] .

Comment: `typeid::name` is not as useful as you'd like it to be. The type really is pointer to `Animal`. Consider adding a `name` virtual function to animal.

Comment: Here's a small example that may help explain the `typeid` issue: https://ideone.com/UWwdXF

Comment: I'm with Ninja. But how far are you willing to go for those eggs? Animals have eggs, but a lot of them don't lay eggs, so depending on what you mean by `GetNumberofEggs`, it may not make sense in `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you try to access to specific child's method, that not defined in the parent class, from an object that has a parent type.

**You should store an object as a type you want to work with**, so if you store an array of `Animal` implies that you will work with objects using only the `Animal` interface, regardless of the initial object type. Otherwise, if you need to access methods from `Opivarous` class you should think about store your objects as `Opivarous` (or `Crocodile`, etc).

Also, you can use `dynamic_cast` for this purpose:

```
if(Crocodile* crocodile = dynamic_cast<Crocodile*>(animals[i]))
{
    cout << crocodile->GetNumberofEggs();
}
```

It is the simplest way to solve a problem, but it shows that there are problems with architecture in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with having a virtual "Print" method on the Animal class, then override this method from the child classes. Thank you everyone!